# Heat map displaying as one solid layer with no difference based on point density

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, heat-map, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to create a heat map in ArcMap 10.4.1. I've already selected a base map, created a shapefile out of my data points, and overlaid that shape onto the map. Next I go tools -> [point density](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/point-density.htm). I set Input Point Features to my shapefile. I click on environments, then Raster Analysis, and then I set mask to my shapefile. Finally I go to Processing Extent and set the boundaries I want using another layer.

After all of this, I get the entire area filled in with one solid uniform color. The densities of the points are not reflected at all. Also, when I look at my table of contents, I see that the ranges for every single color are the same.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you dont mask it to the shapefile?

Comment: Actually now every time I do this, whether I mask it to the shapefile or not, the ranges for all the shades are 0-0 and nothing appears on my map

Comment: have you tried maybe kernel density?

Comment: ok really not sure what happened, but I started completely over with a blank map, recreated the shape file and now it's working. Thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate it!